# Sending data to express backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am learning how to use express, and I am able to get data, but I'm having more trouble figuring out how to send data back to update the backend.  Here is an example of what it looks like.

*server.js*

```
app.route('/animals')
      .get(function (req, res)  {
        res.send({ Cat, Dog, Bear, Wolf, etc... });
      })
      .patch(function (req, res)  {
        console.log('patch is working!')
        // unsure of how to get this called with react or use req here
      })
```

*react front end*

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.callApi()
      .then(res =>  this.setState({ name: res[this.state.animal].name }) )
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  callApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/animals');
    const body = await response.json();

    if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

    return body;
  };
```

This works flawlessly when getting the data, so i have .get down, but I am running into walls trying to use .patch. I can't get the console.log to fire,
 let alone send it data!  (lets say instead of trying to get the animal name, I'm trying to update it's name.)  Any ideas?  Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: fetch('/animals', {
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: {data_you_want_to_send}
    });

Comment: It's more likely you want to use the `PUT` method for updating a resource. Although PATCH is valid, it is not widely used and indicates that other resources may have been changed as a result of the request, not just the record you sent.

Comment: Hello, Thanks!  this got the console.log working.

Unfortunately now, I cant seem to get body parser to show me the body now.  Switching it to put, post, or anything else still doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @DORRITO - how are you post'ing your data when you changed it to post? If you are using postman, did you change the application type to form-data or json/application?

Comment: postman is not being used in this case, I am interacting through react. It looks similar now to what rishikesh shared above.

```fetch('/animals', {
   method: 'PATCH', // POST
   headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
   body: {
    name: 'kitten'
   } })```

Comment: What happens when you bypass react and use your browser to just visit the URL /animals when its set to GET?

Comment: Thanks Usman! Using this an another answer that was provided I solved it!

I still had to use react, but I changed it to a fetch /animals?name=kitten sort of call on the .get to understand it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix in this case was adding  JSON.stringify in addition to what  RishikeshDhokare shared!  I hope this can help someone else down the line.

```
const response = await fetch('/animals', { 
  method: 'PATCH',
  headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}, 
  body: JSON.stringify({ name: 'kitten}) 
});
```